# Make images on server avaialble to clients via http

Tags: php, android, image, video-streaming, server

I'm trying to build a social networking website and mobile app .. I've read that in order to stream videos, you have two options: either HTTP and web services to download file(which is slow and can't serve more than a dozen clients at the same time) or to use a streaming server that makes videos available through HTTP. is that right?

And more importantly, does the same apply to images? how to make images on server available through http? for android mobile app, I'm using picasso framework where it needs the URL of the image.

Comment: *how to make images on server available* just load them into webroot dir ...